# CentOS 7 timedatectl does not work properly with chronyd

Tags: centos, ntp, chrony

In order to have `timedatectl` NTP enabled and synchronized to be `yes`, I had to disable `chronyd`, stop `ntpd`, perfrom `ntpdate`, then start `ntpd`. After that I can get NTP enabled and synchronized in `timedatectl`. For both `/etc/chrony.conf` and `/etc/ntp.conf` I have `server <server-ip> prefer iburst` nothing else.

1. Is there any problem with this situation?
2. Is there a way to force `chrony` to manually sync? Something similar to `ntpdate`?

Answer (score 3):

**timedatectl** works with any ntp *client* (like chrony). systemd supports systemd-timesyncd from v213 but in latest version of CentOS 7 (I am currently on 7.7.1908) they have decided to disabled it.

If you want to use an ntp client instead of timedatectl then I would propose to use cron. **@daily** should do the job.

eg.

```
@daily /usr/sbin/ntpdate -u gr.pool.ntp.org
```

But you can always install chrony and just set ntp true to **timedatectl**

```
# timedatectl set-ntp true 
Failed to set ntp: NTP not supported

# yum -y install chrony

# timedatectl set-ntp true

# timedatectl | grep NTP                                 
     NTP enabled: yes          
NTP synchronized: no
```

and if you enable chrony service, then you will see that timedatectl has also synced NTP

```
# systemctl enable chronyd
# systemctl start chronyd

# timedatectl | grep -i ntp
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

`timedatectl` only works with systemd own NTP daemon (`systemd-timesyncd`), if you are using an other NTP daemon you must use the tools shipped by them (chronyc, ntpq,....)

You definitely shouldn't have multiple NTP daemons running at the same time on your machine.